# Implementing a complex JSX component in the map function

Tags: reactjs, jsx

**My table:**

I have two tables in a MySQL database. The two tables look like this:

- group_table (group_id, group_name)
- item_table (id, group_id, food, qty, price)

After selecting the data from the database using a JOIN operation, the resulting data looks like this:

[image]

**What I am trying to produce:**

I would like to produce output that looks something like this:

[image]

**Everything works fine as one big table:**

I currently have React code that looks like this:

```
render(){
    const data = this.state.data.map((row) => {
        return (
            <tr key={row['id']}>
                <td>{row['food']}</td>
                <td>{row['qty']}</td>
                <td>{row['price']}</td>
            </tr>
         )
     })

     return (
         <div>
              <table>
              <thead>
                   <tr>
                       <th>Food</th>
                       <th>QTY</th>
                       <th>PRICE</th>
                   </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                   {data}
              </tbody>
              </table>
          </div>
     )
}
```

Everything is working fine and everything is displayed in one table.

**Trying to break the big table up by group_name is not working**

So far what I've tried is something along the lines of:

```
render(){
    const the_tables = this.state.data.map((row) => {
        let table_structure = null
        if (group_name != row['group_name']){
            table_structure = (
                   </tbody>
                </table>
                <h2>{row['group_name']}</h2>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Food</th>
                            <th>QTY</th>
                            <th>Price</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
               )
         }

         return (
                {table_structure}
                <tr key={row['id']}>
                   <td>{row['food']}</td>
                   <td>{row['qty']}</td>
                   <td>{row['price']}</td>
                </tr>
             )
       }

       return (
           <div>
                <h1>The main heading</h1>
                {the_tables}
            </div>    
  }
```

That way if a change in the group name is detected as we read the next row, the old table is closed, and a new one is created. I'll also still need to figure out how to deal with the special case of the first table and last table.

**The source of my problem and questions:**

My main problem is that JSX does not allow for unclosed elements. So how can I break the data up into separate tables? How can I handle opening and closing table tags if I cannot specify only a portion of the JSX structure? Is there a different approach I should be taking rather using the .map function?

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing might work in a more template-based framework like Angular or Vue but React requires something a little different.

What you could do is create your `table_stucture` as a React component, making use of `this.props.children` to include the table contents.

For instance:

```
// render()
<TableComponent>
  <tr key={data['id']}>
    <td>{data['item1']}</td>
    <td>{data['item2']}</td>
    <td>{data['item3']}</td>
  </tr>
</TableComponent>
```

The `TableComponent` would look something like:

```
// render()
return (
  <table>
    <thead>
    // header rows
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {this.props.children} // this will output our table data
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Then your loop will return a bunch of `TableComponent` with the required contents. You could also look into `Array.protytype.filter()` to split the array of data into the different groups.

See:

- https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#children-in-jsx
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: This would seem to work if you only had one row in each table, but how about multiple rows?

Comment: I have figured out an answer based on your suggestion and have posted it below. Not sure if it is quite what you had in mind, but it worked well for me. I ended up having to use two .map functions instead of just one. But your idea of using the filter function gave me the insight I needed. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @kojow7 - that looks exactly what I was thinking. I neglected to include the `map` function to output the set of table rows but it looks like you worked that out. Glad I could help you out a little!

Answer (score 1):

Based on Matt Holland's suggestion I came up with the following answer:

```
let group_id = -1;

let data = this.state.data.map((row) => {

    if (row['group_id'] != group_id){
        group_id = row['group_id'];

        let group_rows = this.state.data.filter(group_row =>
            group_row['group_id'] == row['group_id']
        );

        return (
            <TableComponent key={row['group_id']} data={group_rows} group_name={row['group_name']} />

         )
      }
  });
```

And the TableComponent class looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';

class TableComponent extends React.Component {

    render(){

            let rows = this.props.data.map((row) => {
                    return (
                            <tr key={row['id']}>
                                    <td>{row['food']}</td>
                                    <td>{row['qty']}</td>
                                    <td>{row['price']}</td>
                            </tr>
                    )

            })

            return (
                    <div>
                            <h2>{this.props.group_name}</h2>
                            <table>
                            <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                            <th>Food</th>
                                            <th>QTY</th>
                                            <th>Price</th>

                                    </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                    {rows}
                            </tbody>
                            </table>
                    </div>
            )
    }
}

export default TableComponent;
```

For this solution I am using the `.map()` function twice and the `.filter()` function once. If anyone knows a more efficient way, feel free to post an answer here. Other than that, this one is working fine for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

**Tables Component:**

```
class Tables extends Component{
            renderList(data){
                return Object.keys(data).map((key, index) => {
                    return(
                        <Table
                            key={ index }
                            group_name={ key } // Hold group_name
                            table_date={ data[key] }
                        />
                    );
                });
            }


            render(){
                // In here, we create an object array grouped by group_name.
                let newGroupArray = this.state.data.reduce((accu, item) => {

                    // Create new grouped object
                    accu[item.group_name] = accu[item.group_name] || [];
                    accu[item.group_name].push(item);

                    return accu;
                }, {});

                return(
                    <section>
                        { this.renderList(newGroupArray) }
                    </section>
                );
            }
        }
```

**Table Component**

```
  class Table extends Component{

        renderAppointments(){
            return this.props.group_name.map((data, index) => {
                return(
                    <tr key={ index }>
                        <td>{ data.food }</td>
                        <td>{ data.qty }</td>
                        <td>{ data.price }</td>
                    </tr>
                );
            });
        }

        render(){
            return(
                      <table className="table">
                          <thead>
                              <tr>
                                  <td>Food</td>
                                  <td>Qty</td>
                                  <td>Price</td>
                              </tr>
                          </thead>
                          <tbody>
                                { this.renderTableData() }
                          </tbody>
                      </table>
            );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to close the JSX and make sure to expose the .map function with the table_structure and